# ActiveRecord model for users who have issues or who assist with issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record, polymorphism

I'm running into an issue while playing around with some models in a Rails app. Namely issues of the polymorphic variety. I think I may have solved it, more or less looking for an approval.

I have the following models in my app:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :user_issues
  has_many :helpers, through: :user_issues, source: :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues, foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :user_issues
  has_many :issues_helped, through: :user_issues, source: :issues
end

class UserIssues < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :issue
end
```

Scenario:

`UserOne` creates an issue and is saved as the `IssueOne`'s creator. `UserTwo` decides to help `UserOne` and joins/follows `IssueOne` (`has_many :issues_helped` declared in the model) and is allowed to post a comment. `UserTwo` is a helper in this instance.

Well, `UserTwo` is now in need of some help and creates a new issue of his own. `UserTwo` is the creator of `IssueTwo`. `UserOne` decides to help out his new buddy `UserTwo` on his issue and joins/follows `IssueTwo`, and is allowed to post a comment. `UserOne` has now become a helper in this instance.

1. Is this the Rails way of doing it? This is the best solution I have come up with, so far.
2. Am I misusing the power of `has_many :x, through: :y, source: :z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key is not needed for `belongs_to :creator` since rails will infer this foreign key from the association name. The source has to point to the relation for `UserIssue` (you pluralized this name but active record class names should be singularized in most cases) so instead of `source: users`, and `source: issues`, you want `source: user`, `source: issue`.

Another way you could have accomplished the same thing, which IMO is a bit cleaner is the following:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :helpings, :foreign_key => 'issue_helped_id'
  has_many :helpers, through: :helpings
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues, foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :helpings, foreign_key: 'helper_id'
  has_many :issues_helped, through: :helpings
end

class Helping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :helper, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :issue_helped, class_name: 'Issue'
end
```

It also gives the join table a more descriptive name. For this to work you need to modify your inflections since rails cannot pluralize `issue_helped` or singularize `issues_helped` out of the box. To do this, in `config/initializers/inflections.rb` add:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'issue_helped', 'issues_helped'
  inflect.singular 'issues_helped', 'issue_helped'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't for the life of me come up with a name but your code could definitely benefit so I'm going to use an analogous example of how one would use comments(assume User exists -- perhaps making use of devise or similar framework)

```
   class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      include Commentable
    end 

   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      include Commentable 
   end 
   class Comments < Active::Record::Base
      belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true 
      belongs_to :user
   end


  module Commentable 
     extend ActiveSupport::Concern

     included do
       has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
       accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments #allows for you to do @image.comments  
     end
  end
```

Now you've DRY'd up your code and it looks clean...and if you wanted to make a Video resource -- you can do the same and it looks clean. I'm not sure if it's premature in your case, I'm just learning myself and figured I'd share what I'm learning. <3

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We're looking for extended answers that are more than just a link.

Comment: I've edited it to be more concrete and included an example...PS a code editor would be nice on StackExchange :-)

Comment: You could in your example make it Helpable but putting code that will be repeated potentially in a concern is good practice